# Modele constructor called twice

Tags: angular

I have a module with 2 static function forRoot() and forChild() but when the child is called

```
TranslateModule.forChild({
  provide: TranslateLoader,
  useFactory: translateLoaderFactory,
  deps: [Http]
})
```

my module constructor is called twice when a call `forChild` in my module application and juste one time in my app.module why is the reason ?

```
    constructor(public loader: ModuleLoader) {
          this.loader.init();
    }
    static forRoot(providedLoader: any = {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: translateLoaderFactory,
        deps: [Http]
    }): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: TranslateModule,
            providers: [
                providedLoader,
                ModuleLoader,
                { provide: ModuleIdentifier, useValue: {uid: 'root'} },
                TranslateService,
                { provide: TranslateParser, useClass: DefaultTranslateParser }, 
            ]
        };
    }
    static forChild(providedLoader: any = {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: translateLoaderFactory,
        deps: [Http]
    }): ModuleWithProviders {
        let uid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g,
          function(c: string) {
              var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16),
                  v = c === 'x' ? r : (r % 4 + 4);
              return v.toString(16);
          }).toUpperCase();
        console.log("xxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx", uid);
        return {
            ngModule: TranslateModule,
            providers: [
                providedLoader,
                ModuleLoader,
                { provide: ModuleIdentifier, useValue: {uid: uid}}, 
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: bug is here : https://plnkr.co/edit/DC61YtBNkPwuFj3RFJl8?p=preview test is logged twice when forchild function is called why ? Is a angular2 bug?

Comment: in fact is a angular2 bug it will be merge later